# How to set the superclass instance within the initialization of subclass

Tags: objective-c, oop, superclass

I am curious how to instead of doing:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
         //initialize subclass objects
    }
    return self;
}
```

Initialize the subclass by passing a perimeter of the superclass object

```
- (id)initWithSuperclass:(Superclass *)superclassObject {
    if ((self = superclass)) {
        //initialize subclass objects
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is this possible and if so, is it something that I should avoid? To me, it reeks of smelly code but I don't see another way of passing all the data fields of a superclass object to an initialization of a subclass without knowing every data field in the superclass.

Anyone following my thought/able to help me figure a way through this... smelly code?

Edit:

Ok, so say I have class A and class B below:

```
@interface A
    //stuff but we don't know what
end

@implementation A

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
         //initialize A "stuff"
    }
    return self;
}

end

@interface B : A  
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton* one;
    - initWithA:(A*)superclassObject;
end

@implementation B

- (id)initWithA:(A*)superclassObject {
    if ((self = superclassObject)) {
        one = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

end
```

The advantage to doing this that I am looking for is that in class A, I do not know all the data fields because it is not my code/code I have access to. I do however need to extend that class. I want to be able to change instances of class A into class B by introducing new data values for class B (like "UIButton one" in the above example) on top of whatever data values/objects may be part of the object instance of class A.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please give a concrete code example what you think does not work in the first example, but works in the second example?

Comment: I edited my question to be (what I thought was) more concrete. I added an A class - B class code example.

Comment: This is still hard to understand. Let's call the two initializers you are presenting variant 1 and 2. In your example code you show how to use variant 2 to create a `UIButton` instance. I don't see why you can't do the same with variant 1. Also, you are saying "I want to be able to change instances of class A into class B". Does this mean that something out of your control is creating instances of `A`, and you want to somehow change those already existing instances into instances of `B`?

Comment: Ok, so say I have a UIButton. I subclass that UIButton as MYButton. Now I want to take the UIButton objects that I already have and turn them into MYButton objects. Since I don't for sure know all the data fields of UIButton, is that even possible? According to CRD it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring obscure advanced features of the runtime, what you are trying to do is not possible in Objective-C - you cannot dynamically extend an object instance from a superclass to a subclass instance adding instance variables in the process.

Think instead of the "has a" model - where `B` is not a subclass of `A` but has an instance variable/property of type `A`.

HTH

**Addendum**

Seeing your new comments regarding `MYButton` vs `UIButton`, why create `UIButton` instances at all? If you are using Interface Builder/Xcode to generate your UI then you can construct your `MYButton`s directly - select a `UIButton` in the designer and change its class to `MYButton`, see the docs for how, and then you'll create your instances directly.

Comment: Are you saying DO think of it as a "has a" model? You say think instead of the model as... and then it's not clear what you are suggesting I think of it as.

Comment: I mean you should think of solving your problem using the "has a" model.

Comment: So you are saying instead of subclassing A, I should make B contain a property of A?

Comment: I'm just suggesting it as one option for you to consider.

Comment: I would love that option and have thought of it, unfortunately, the actual problem I'm solving by subclassing is that UIButton.titleLabel is read only so I am replacing that label with a label that (1) handles it's own layout/font for a CGRect size by default or can be told exactly how to lay out itself inside the UIButton subclass. Since I must override the methods in UIButton and still have everything else consider my object to be a UIButton, I must subclass it. For others who see this question, this very well may be the solution they are looking for. Thanks for the answer to my question.